# How to control order of executed Bamboo modules

Tags: module, continuous-integration, bamboo

Assuming I have 3 post-chain-modules named A, B, and C. How do I control the order of their execution? Maybe I want to run them in B, C, A order. Anyway to do that? What is the logic Bamboo uses to order execution of modules?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Atlassian Bamboo 5.2.2 source code, the logic for executing build processors is in a method named `performCustomBuildProcess` in com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.tasks.ExecuteBuildTask.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's a way to control the order of execution. `performCustomBuildProcess` iterates over a `List`. While a `List` maintains the order that objects are inserted, the `List` used in `performCustomBuildProcess` is initialized by iterating over `Collection` objects. Java doesn't guarantee the order of objects in a `Collection`.

I believe your only option is to have a single `BuildProcessor` module. This `BuildProcessor` would control the order that other Java code is executed.

Comment: Yea that's pretty much what I took away from searching the internets :( Unfortunately we have somewhere around 10 different post-chain actions and can't seem to find a way to force one to execute before the other

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and prefixed each task with a number. So far, these have executed in numerical order. Within a given stage, the tasks should execute in the order show on the task list screen. Between stages, its harder to control execution order, short of using artifacts.